# Existence of an orthogonal matrix that converts $AB$ to $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, such that $AB,BA$ are symmetric matrices. How do we show that there exists an orthogonal matrix $T$, such that $T^{-1}ABT=BA$?

Comment: Where does this question come from? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any question at all.

Comment: @Graphth In math books, theorems to be proved are commonly just stated in the exercises. It's clear the problem is to prove the assertion in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AB = U_1V_1U_1^T$, where $U_1$ is the matrix formed by eigenvectors of $AB$, and $V_1$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues. Note $U_1U_1^T = I$

Suppose $BA = U_2V_2U_2^T$, and $V_2 = V_1$ ($AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues), we have

$U_1^TABU_1 = V_2$, so

$U_2U_1^TABU_1U_2^T = BA$, and $T = U_1U_2^T$